# PHPUnit 8, how to set dynamically set testdox description

Tags: phpunit

I'm using `@testdox` annotation in PHPUnit 8 to set the description for my tests.

This works fine, but I'd like to be able to set the description dynamically. A method like this would be nice:

```
$this->setTestDoxDescription("My super test routine for date: ".$mydate->format('Y-m-d');
```

I have tests that check the results of various date-related functions.  Many of the tests are relative to today's date, so the input date values are not fixed and are generated dynamically.  I would like to be able to print the date values in the description.

I just discovered the `setName()` method in `TestCase` and it seems to do mostly what I want:

```
$this->setName("My super test routine for date: ".$mydate->format('Y-m-d');
```

However, there is some kind of parsing and it is splitting my dates on `-` chars and adding extra spaces.  For example, `2020-04-04` is changed to `2020- 04- 04`.  But if I use `@testdox 2020-04-04` it does not split things. It is only a problem when I use `setName()`. Not a big deal, but kind of annoying.

I've solved my problem for now, but maybe someone can recommend a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put variable names into the @testdox string, the variables that are being returned from the @dataprovider (given as the method parameters).

An example from phpunit's own tests...

```
/**
 * @testdox Valid regex $pattern on $subject returns $return
 * @dataProvider validRegexpProvider
 *
 * ....
 */
public function testValidRegex($pattern, $subject, $return): void
```

I've just added it to my own tests and one dataprovider/testdox output example is:

> @testdox displayNumber formats $input as '$expectedLong' & '$expectedShort'
>
> public function testNumber($input, $expectedLong, $expectedShort): void {}
>
> ✔ displayNumber formats 1781234 as '1,781,234' & '1.8M'

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was looking at the `@dataProvider` stuff but did not realize you could plug the variables into `@testdox`.  I also discovered that any dataProvider methods get called before the `setupBeforeClass()` method, so I had to rearrange a few things to make it all work.